# Difference between uppercase Enum and lowercase enum

Tags: java, enums

What is the difference between using the lowercase keyword *enum* and the uppercase class name *Enum* to define a class?

```
public enum Apple {
    RedDelicious, GrannySmith;
}

public Enum Pony {
    Earth, Pegasus, Unicorn
}
```

The second version is not correct anyway, as I am not familiar with the correct syntax of that method of creating Enums, but apparently, something similar is possible.

My apologies if this question seems as though it lacks research effort, but that is not the case; due to the casing issue, this information is *not* easy to find via Google, IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `enum` keyword is part of the Java language. `Enum` is the name of the `Class` object that represents an `enum`; that is, it is the common base class for all `enum` values. It defines the methods that all enum objects inherit: `name()`, `ordinal()`, etc. Think of it like an analogy question from the old SAT: `enum` is to `Enum` as `class` is to `Object`.

Always use `enum` in your code for declaring enumerations.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason for "always" using this one method over the other?  If the alternative method is possible, surely there is some reason for it?

Comment: @SouthpawHare - The alternative method is not possible. It makes no more sense than declaring a regular class using the syntax `public Class Foo { ... }`. It just doesn't work. `Enum` and `enum` mean two completely different things.

Comment: I like that analogy!  That clarifies things entirely, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`enum` is the reserved word used to define a new enumeration.

`Enum` is an abstract class, that comes with the JDK.

If you want to define a new enumeration, use `enum`

You can refer to `Enum` documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) if you want any further clarification.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason for "always" using this one method over the other?  If the alternative method is possible, surely there is some reason for it?

Comment: What you mean the alternative method is possible? You can't define an enumerator using `Enum`

Comment: I was under the impression that there was some way that was possible, based on what a friend told me - however, I'd never seen it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly create subclasses of `Enum` : you use the `enum` keyword to let the compiler build this class for you.

The `Enum` class is just present in the javadoc so that you can read the documentation of the standard non static method that all enumerations will have (not that some special static methods aren't described here, for examples `values`).

This mechanism is described here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html